# SQL + BigQuery - maximum over a few days

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've got a BQ table that contains the records for emails students has sent to each other and has the following fields:

- student_id
- time_sent
- destination_student_id
- content
  ... (there are more but these are the only relevant fields)

Each row of the table represents an email that was sent from one student to another.

What I wanna do is to get a list of each student id and the maximum emails sent in a day in the last 3 days.

for example:

**student_id, max_mails_in_a_day_for_past_3_days**

1,  44

2,          12

3,          7

These results would mean that the student with Id of 1 has sent a max number of 44 emails in a day in the past 3 days, student with id of 2 has sent 12 etc..

(sorry for the weird format, I could not find how to create a table here)

How can I achieve that?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the data type of `time_sent`?  What do you mean by "last three days"?  Are those calendar days?  Based on 24 hours periods from the current time?  Calendar days in the local timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want aggregation and filtering.  Making some assumptions:

- `time_sent` is a `timestamp`
- You want calendar days UTC.
- And you want going back three complete days from the current time

Then:

```
select student_id, max(num_emails)
from (select student_id, timestamp_trunc(time_sent, day) as dte,
             count(*) as num_emails
      from t
      where time_sent >= timestamp_add(timestamp_trunc(current_timestamp, day), interval -3 day)
      group by 1, 2
     ) t
group by student_id;
```

All of those assumptions can be modified with tweaks to the query.

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL (and assumes `time_sent` column is of `timestamp` data type)

```
select student_id, max(emails_sent) max_mails_in_a_day_for_past_3_days
from (
  select student_id, date(time_sent) date_sent, count(*) emails_sent
  from `project.dataset.table`
  where date(time_sent) > current_date() - 3 
  group by student_id, date_sent
)
group by student_id
```